# Non-modular elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Do we have any examples of non-modular elliptic curves over number fields $K \neq \mathbb{Q}$?

In particular, I came across a paper by Freitas, Le Hung, and Siksek, "[Elliptic curves over real quadratic fields are modular](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-014-0550-z)", which shows that there are at most finitely many non-modular elliptic curves over a fixed totally real number field. Is there any known example of $E/K$ where $E$ is a non-modular elliptic curve and $K$ is a totally real number field?

Comment: There seems to be a unique paper by Freitas, Le Hung, and Siksek, "[Elliptic curves over real quadratic fields are modular](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-014-0550-z)", so I edited its title into your question.  I hope that was the correct paper.

Comment: @LSpice The statement of the result also sounds like the main theorem in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4134) paper of Le Hung. Perhaps that one was meant.

Comment: Title of the paper [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424457/non-modular-elliptic-curves#comment1091350_424457) by @Wojowu:  [Le Hung - Modularity of some elliptic curves over totally real fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4134).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a widely believed conjecture that all elliptic curves, over any number field $K$, are modular (in the sense that there exists an automorphic representation [*] $\pi$ of $\operatorname{GL}_2 / K$ whose $L$-function is the same as that of $E$). No counterexamples are known, and it would be *extremely* big and disturbing news for number theory if somebody stumbled across one.

([*] If you are surprised not to see the word "cuspidal" here, then there's a reason for that: you need to take non-cuspidal $\pi$ if $E$ has CM, and the field it has CM by is a subfield of $K$. In all other cases $\pi$ will be cuspidal. In particular, if you are only looking at totally-real $K$, then you can validly write "cuspidal" there.)